# retrieve local storage at regular intervals

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In order to append `<form>` `inputs` to `localStorage`, I'm using this piece of code:

```
function appendToStorage(name, data){
   var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
   if(old === null) old = '';
   localStorage.setItem(name, old + data);
}
userInputs();

function userInputs() {
   appendToStorage('oldData', $('textarea[name="textbox"]').val());
}
```

but I want to retrieve `localStorage` and process its individual words, `split by`spaces, every minute or so.

Does this...

```
   function setInput(){
       var input = userInputs();
       setInterval(function(){localStorage.getItem(name)}, 60000);
    }
```

...make any sense?

Comment: *"Is there a more efficient way to achieve this result?"* - Well yes, given the result of the code shown for `setInput()` is to do nothing, it would be more efficient to just not have it at all. If you want to do something every minute then `setInterval()` is the way to go, but you seem to know that. So what are you actually trying to ask us to help with?

Comment: @nnnnnn but `userInput()` returns `.val()`, no? do you know how I could make the last `function` work?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original comment. But no, `userInputs()` returns `undefined` because it doesn't have an explicit `return` statement. So the `input` variable in `setInput()` will be `undefined`, but in any case you don't use that variable again so... Have you actually tried to do anything with the return value from `localStorage.getItem(name)`?

Comment: Besides code bugs, I am simply trying to wrap my head around the design intention here. You have a form whose contents you want in localStorage, correct? Presumably the live form should be the "master"... if you pull from localStorage every minute, you have the potential to overwrite user input. Why does it need to come out of localStorage at intervals at all? I would think a one-time "pre-populate my form with localStorage values" would suffice.

Comment: @nnnnnn so if I `return` the value inside `userInputs()` and then again `return` ìnput inside `setInput()`, do I end up with an array so I can process the words? sorry, newbie here.

Comment: @GregPettit I'm testing for a chat bot. so, the designs's intention is to simulate several interactions, each one being appended to localStorage. then I would like to recall the full history of "interactions" at regular intervals so I could further process it .